# Is !0 and !1 better than 1 and 0?

Tags: javascript

I noticed that Closure Compiler compiles true and false (or 1 and 0) as !0 and !1. This doesn't make sense to me since it's twice as many characters as 1 and 0. Is there a reason for this? Is there any benefit?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`1 !== true` and `0 !== false`, but `!0 === true` and `!1 === false`. The compiler just makes sure the type stays boolean.

Consider this example:

```
var a = true;

if( a === true ) {
    console.log( 'True!' );
}

if( a === 1 ) {
    console.log( 'You should never see this.' );
}
```

If you change the first line to `var a = 1;` the first conditional would be false and the second true. Using `var a = !0;` the script would still work correctly.

Comment: `!0` has the added benefit of saving 2 characters and `!1` has the added benefit of saving 3, during minification.  Way over-optimized, but if a machine is doing the optimizing, who cares.